# Divergence of series

Tags: mathematical-physics

How do I understand whether a series will diverge at some point?

For example, in the [Legendre's diff. equation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre_polynomials) $$(1-z^2)y' '-2zy'+\ell(\ell+1)y~=~0,$$
does 
$y(z)$ diverge for $z=-1$ and $z=+1$?

Comment: Would [math.se] be a better home for this question?

Comment: Oh okay. Then I'll post it there.

Comment: Why can't I see this question in the mathematics site?

Comment: Math.SE probably rejected the migration.

Comment: Then how/where do I get the answer? :(

Comment: @Qmechanic Please don't lock my question, so that at least I can get an answer here. Anyway I don't even study Math; I study Physics. And I had this doubt while studying Lengendre's equation.

Comment: I would say it is off-topic, but let me ask in the [hbar chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/11900253#11900253) for a second opinion.

Comment: @ShaonaBose We're actually somewhat confused why math.SE rejected the question, too. I suggest posting a new question there (make no mistake, this is a math question, not a physics one, regardless of what context it appeared in), maybe expanding a little on what you've tried or tinkered with. At the very least, if it's closed again they'll have to give a reason and you can work with them to get the question up to their standards.

Comment: @ChrisWhite That's because Maths.SE **didn't** reject the migration. The OP voluntarily deleted it there.

Comment: To the OP: To get an answer, just undelete this: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/542915/divergence-of-series